# Opening sasbdat7 files using the sasbdat7 package in R

Tags: r, import, sas

I am having difficulty opening `sas7bdat` files using R studio.
There is a bit of content around for the `haven` package, however it seems as though it hasn't been updated for the current version of R, so I am using the `sas7bdat` package. Below is the code I have used. This file is around 130mb, is not corrupted and is fine in SAS.
Is there something I am missing in my code or is there a more reliable method for importing large `sas7bdat` files?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sas7bdat)

> raw <- read.sas7bdat("c:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4\\folder5\\folder6\\folder7\\datasetx.sas7bdat")
> str(raw)
# function (length = 0L)*
> head(raw)                                  
# 1 function (length = 0L)          
# 2 .Internal(vector("raw", length))*

> view(raw)
```

[image: dataoutput]

Comment: I don't think your `read.sas7bdat` call has worked at all. What you are seeing in `head(raw)` is just the base R function `?raw`. Take a look at the results of running your `raw <- read.sas7bdat(...` line again and take note of any 'errors' that pop up.

Comment: haven package can read in sas7bdat files with haven::read_sas("filename.sas7bdat")

Maybe check your versions and path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your R and package versions are up to date

```
sessionInfo()
packageVersion("haven")
packageVersion("tidyverse")
```

Output should read:

R version 4.0.0 or 4.0.1 or 4.0.2, depending on when you downloaded newer R 4.0

Haven package was updated to CRAN on 6/1/2020 and should read as version 2.3.0

Tidyverse was updated to CRAN on 11/21/2019  and should read as version 1.3.0

Update packages if needed. Then try:

```
raw <- haven::read_sas("c:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4\\folder5\\folder6\\folder7\\datasetx.sas7bdat")
```